# Dynamically evaluating code at runtime

Tags: fantom

Is it possible to take a string/AST of source code and evaluate it (like eval()) at runtime in Fantom? I found some suggesting features in the documentation but not obvious evidence.

Comment: Which parts of the documentation were you looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as calling an `eval()` function, but it is possible. You need to first compile your [Fantom](http://fantom.org/) code into a class before you can execute it.

[Plastic](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afPlastic/), a library from Alien-Factory, does just that. Example:

```java
using afPlastic

class Example {
    Void main() {
        eval("2 + 2")  // --> 4
    }

    Obj? eval(Str code) {
        model := PlasticClassModel("MyClass", true)
        model.addMethod(Obj?#, "eval", "", code)
        myType := PlasticCompiler().compileModel(model.toFantomCode)
        return myType.make->eval()
    }
}
```

The [PlasticCompiler](https://bitbucket.org/AlienFactory/afplastic/src/default/fan/public/PlasticCompiler.fan) class does the job of compiling Fantom code into a usable Type.

It uses the Fantom [compiler](http://fantom.org/doc/compiler/index.html) library and is based on code found in [Fansh](http://fantom.org/doc/docTools/Fansh.html) - a Fantom shell, part of the Fantom distribution.